# WMI query in VB.NET - access denied

Tags: .net, vb.net, wmi

I am getting access denied when running the below code with alternate credentials ('Access is denied (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

If I run the whole program under standard credentials, then pass an Administrator username & password into the WMI connection options, then I get access denied.  If however I right-click on the program and choose "RunAs" and put in an Administrator username & password (without passing credentials to the WMI options) then it works!  I gather from this that the account has the required privileges and that all the required ports are open so I don't believe this is a DCOM issue.

I have also tried the wbemtest program and can connect to the remote PC just by entering username and password.  I can always connect no matter which options I choose for impersonation & authentication level. In the program, I have experimented by putting various parameters for these options (see the commented lines) and have also tried the .EnablePrivileges option but no combination of these will make the program work.  What am I missing here?

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim myConnectionOptions As New System.Management.ConnectionOptions
    With myConnectionOptions
        '.EnablePrivileges = True
        '.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
        '.Authentication = System.Management.AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy
        If TextBoxUserName.Text <> "" Then
            .Username = TextBoxUserName.Text
            .Password = TextBoxPassword.Text
        End If
    End With
    'Establish connection
    Try
        Dim myManagementScope As System.Management.ManagementScope
        myManagementScope = New System.Management.ManagementScope( _
            "\\" & TextBoxComputerName.Text & "\root\cimv2", myConnectionOptions)
        'Connect to WMI namespace
        myManagementScope.Connect()
        Dim myObjectSearcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( _
            myManagementScope.Path.ToString, "Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem")
        Dim myCollection As ManagementObjectCollection
        Dim myObject As ManagementObject
        'Execute query
        myCollection = myObjectSearcher.Get()
        For Each myObject In myCollection
            If myObject.GetPropertyValue("UserName") Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox("Ctrl-Alt-Del")
            Else
                MsgBox(myObject.GetPropertyValue("UserName").ToString)
            End If
        Next
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox("_Connection Error" & e.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi ! Remove the comments for you ConnectOptions, this is really required; Additionally, specify ".Authority = "NTLMDOMAIN:" + computerName" for the connection. [Have you tried "dom\user" format??].

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the WMI configuration is correct in the remote PC

in your code you need to pass the "myManagementScope" as object and create query object and pass it both to object searcher.

The below code in your code didn't pass the credentials to the OjectSearcher, change the below code

```
    Dim myObjectSearcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( _
        myManagementScope.Path.ToString, "Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem")
```

to

```
    Dim x ObjectQuery
    x = New ObjectQuery("Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem")

    Dim myObjectSearcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( _
        myManagementScope, x)
```